# How to simulate input disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like simulate input disabled. I would like don't have change value in input, but this value should be send with POST with FORM.

```
<input class="dis" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="111">
<input class="no" type="text">
<input class="dis" type="text" disabled="disabled" value="333">
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/hC4WP/

I can use also CSS and jQuery, but how?

Comment: Mark the field as `readonly`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [submit disabled fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284464/submit-disabled-fields)

Comment: I know this is an old thread but... Attribute `readonly` allows you to modify it. You should do something like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `readonly` attribute instead of `disabled`.

However, this will not result in the field being grayed out. To achieve this, use the following CSS:

```
input[readonly] { color: #aaa; }
```

(you might have to change the color a bit to look more like the original disabled color)

Comment: I know this is an old thread but... Attribute `readonly` allows you to modify it. You should do something like this: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368813/html-form-readonly-select-tag-input

Answer (score 11):

Use `readonly` instead of `disabled`

Answer (score 0):

Solution with tabindex.

Create a .disabled class.

CSS:

```
.disabled {
    pointer-events:none; /* No cursor */
    background-color: #eee; /* Gray background */
}
```

JS:

```
$(".disabled").attr("tabindex", "-1");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="disabled" />
```

Comment: what about the not allowed icon?

Comment: "cursor: not-allowed" would not work here because "pointer-events:none" disables cursor events. This means the cursor won't change when hovering inputs. I believe you could add the "cursor" property to a parent element to achieve the same result though.