# jQuery / JSON and ASP.NET reading / serializing form fields

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1, $.ajax, Javascript, JSON and ASP.NET and have some issues with it. When submitting the form to a ASP.NET PageMethod not all the formfields are serialized or are empty. When I debug the code, nothing is wrong, so maybe you can help me.

I submit a form like this in javascript

```
function SaveFormData() {

    var fields = $("form").serializeArray();
    var myData = { 'projectId': projectId, 'fields': fields };

    myData = JSON.stringify(myData);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/w2/AspNetPage.aspx/SaveForm",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        timeout: (1000 * 60 * 10),
        data: (myData),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert('done');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

My AspNetPage.aspx contains the webmethod SaveForm:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveForm(int projectId, field[] fields) {
    // do the processing here
}
```

To read and process the formdata I'm using the class field which is needed to serialize between javascript / JSON and ASP.NET.

```
public class field {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes not all the formfields are posted, or are empty. I can't find the problem by debugging it, so maybe you can help me with this. Keep in mind that the form can have over a few hundred of form fields.

I was also wondering if the code i'm using now is thread safe, and maybe I have to process my form data different than now.

Please help

Comment: Where are the fields missing sometimes: server or client?

Comment: problem solved!, I used a static field to store my field[], that was very dangerous, so I've now a new  solution without static stuff. jQuery and SerializeForm works great! No problems there. It was my mistake to use static fields / properties to process the form data

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your form **fields are not disabled**.

Disabled fields can't be posted to server

Refer

[values of disabled inputs will not be submited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355728/values-of-disabled-inputs-will-not-be-submited)

[submit disabled fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284464/submit-disabled-fields)

Hope this may helpful!

Comment: hi i'm sure form fields are NOT disabled